# Probability histogram

Tags: graphics, histograms

Is there a quick way to draw a probability histogram as e.g. [here](http://www.statisticslectures.com/topics/probabilityhistograms/) or [here, page 166](https://books.google.com/books?id=MAyXDk7ayLoC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=mathematica%20probability%20histogram&source=bl&ots=54xwwrVZOB&sig=ACfU3U2VNk-yGDELTV1ezW2vBEBvYcz8tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr75Cgs6LoAhWUGc0KHdpEAioQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20probability%20histogram&f=false), say for a binomial distribution, with the bases of the rectangles centered at the integers and no spacing between the rectangles? In the book at the second link, they use Needs["KnoxProb`Utilities`"], but this does not seem to be working now (in Mathematica 12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exact probabilities:

```
BarChart[
 PDF[BinomialDistribution[4, .5], r=Range[0, 4]],
 BarSpacing -> None,
 ChartLabels -> r]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf = PDF[BinomialDistribution[4, .5]];
```

#### DiscretePlot

```
DiscretePlot[pdf@x, {x, 0, 4}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image]

#### Histogram with custom heights

```
heights = pdf /@ Range[0, 4] &;
binning = {-.5, 4.5, 1};

Histogram[{1}, binning, heights]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1